# Django - PageNotFound after login

Tags: python, django

Django 2.1 does not obey my configuration in settings. After logging in, I get the error:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:
>   GET Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/index.html

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard/index'
```

Login URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/
```

myproject/urls.py

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index/index.html'), name='index'),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
```

dashboard/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.dashboard_index, name='dashboard_index'),
]
```

dashboard/views.py

```
@login_required
def dashboard_index(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {})
```

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps it's because your view URL is `/dashboard/index/`, but you're redirecting to `/dashboard/index` (without the trailing slash).

Comment: it seems in your configuration you have typo error or you declear LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL more than once

Comment: I think you need a slash at the beginning of `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard/index'`, otherwise it thinks it's a relative url and it will just append `dashboard/index` to the end of the current url.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I still can not. I tried following the doc: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

Tried: "named URL patterns" unsuccessfully.

'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard_index''
'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard:dashboard_index''

Comment: If everything is set as it should be I upvote John Gordon's comments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The problem was with the form button, it was wrong. There was no "submit" type and pointed to an html page.

Before:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="index.html">Login</a>
```

After:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
```